# Missing operand issue, while filtering a DataTable with DataView

Tags: c#, filtering, dataview

I am still facing a `missing operand` issue, even after taking care of any potential spacing issue using `String.Format`, and hope to understand the rationale.

The below method is used as an illustration:

```
public static DataTable FilterByCategory(DataTable dt)
    {
        string category = "C4";
        DataView view = dt.DefaultView;
        view.RowFilter = string.Format("Info dedicated to Printer LIKE '%{0}%'", category);
        DataTable ds = view.ToTable();
        return ds;
    }
```

`SyntaxErrorException: Missing operand after 'dedicated' operator`

**PS**: "**Info dedicated to Printer**" is the filtered column on `dt`, and my reference has been: [DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use brackets [] for columns whose names contain the space character :

```
view.RowFilter = string.Format("[Info dedicated to Printer] LIKE '%{0}%'", category);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thank you too :)